# How to make for loops go backwards?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I wrote some code for Matrix backwards calculation but for some reason it goes from 3 to 2 but it won't go from 3 to 1. If I tell it to go from 3 to 1 it completely jumps instructions.

```
function [x] = backwards(U,b)

[n,n]=size(U);
x(n)=b(n)/U(n,n);

for i=n-1:1     
           sum=0;
        for k=i+1:n
            sum=sum+(U(i,k)*x(k));
            x(i)=(b(i)-sum)/U(i,i);
        end      
end

fprintf('solution:');
fprintf('\n');
disp(x');

end
```

Comment: You need to specify the step: `i=n-1:-1:1`

Comment: thanks a lot!!!! it worked you saved my life